# How to increase this search query in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, search, find, keyword, partials

Here my actual query :

```
router.get('/fiches', (req, res) => {

  // Here I convert the input into normalized unique lowercased words
  let words = Utils.normalizeIntoWords(req.query.q)
  
  // The keywords property is autogenerated on save. It contains some keywords lowercased and unique.
  Fiche.find({ keywords: { '$all': words } }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json([])
    return res.json(data)
  })
})
```

How to increase the query to include "partials words" ?

EDIT : Here the solution :

```
router.get('/fiches', (req, res) => {
  let words = Utils.words(req.query.q).map(word => new RegExp('^' + word))
  Fiche.find({ keywords: { '$all': words } }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json([])
    return res.json(data)
  })
})
```

"$all" is magic, you can pass array of regex ! Marvelous :)

Answer (score 1):

router.get('/fiches', (req, res) => {

```
  // Here I convert the input into normalized unique lowercased words
  let words = Utils.normalizeIntoWords(req.query.q)
  
  // The keywords property is autogenerated on save. It contains some keywords lowercased and unique.
  Fiche.find({ keywords: { '$regex': words } }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json([])
    return res.json(data)
  })
})
```

regex operator is really powerfull, for more info about it an options: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

hope it will be usefull!

Comment: Thx the "$regex" not work because my "keywords" property is an array. I try "$in" with "words" as array of regex and it's better. It allow to search partials words. But the "$in" work as "$or" so the results aren't consistent.